# Running ARM64 binaries on RP4

Tags: raspbian, 64-bit, gcc, golang

I'm trying to run an ARM64 [binary](https://github.com/cloudflare/cloudflared/releases) on my RP4 with `arm_64bit` enabled in `/boot/config.txt`. I get an error: `No such file or directory`.

Running `file cloudflared-linux-arm64` I get:

```
cloudflared-linux-arm64: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1, for GNU/Linux 3.7.0 [truncated]
```

So the architecture is `aarch64`. Then I make sure this matches my system:

```
Linux <hostname> 5.10.17-v8+ #1403 SMP PREEMPT Mon Feb 22 11:37:54 GMT 2021 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

So, it looks like they match. Then I run `ldd`:

```
$ ldd cloudflared-linux-arm64 
    not a dynamic executable
```

I think the problem is that the output of `file` says it wants to use the `/lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1` interpreter, but that doesn't exist on my RP4. This is what I have:

```
ls /lib/ld-*
/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3  /lib/ld-linux.so.3
```

Does anyone know how to run binaries targeted for ARM64? This particular binary was compiled from Go, if that's helpful.

Comment: A per the answer you need a 64-bit userland as well as a the kernel: "I think the problem is that the output of file says it wants to use the /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 interpreter, but that doesn't exist on my RP4" -> It does in the 64-bit RpiOS.  Try `file` on a system executable (such as the linker/loader or just `/bin/bash`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are most likely using Raspbian with a 64-bit kernel and 32-bit userland.

You need to use a distribution with 64-bit kernel and 64-bit userland. The latest beta of Raspbian seems to work. See also: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=277116

Answer (score 3):

The 64-bit Pi OS is available [here](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_arm64/images/) and [here](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_lite_arm64/images/) (for the "lite" version). You must be using one of these if you intend to run 64-bit applications.

The kernel architecture has no direct impact on userland. A quick check for your current userland architecture can be done with:

```
dpkg-architecture --list
```